# How to update the pagenation active tab in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I my web page i have two pagination parts are there one is at Top and another is at Bottom

Here when i am click on any page number that will update in that particular pagination

For suppose i am click on 5th page number at top of the pagination it will update and it shows 5th page is active tab .... but bottom pagination still in 1st page number active

and same as bottom pagination also

can you please give me the suggestion how to update both pagination's in single action

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question to get better answers.

Comment: Call the same state on both parts.

Answer (score 0):

When you are handling the event of page change in top change the state of the current page and use that state variable at both the places so, that your state will be centralized. Let me know if any more assistance is required.
You can use this

```
this.setState({
    currentPage: clickedPage
)}
```

to set the state of your current page